# enumerateObjectsUsingBlock - casting parameters in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray

I want to refer to enumerated objects with their specific type, instead of just a generic `AnyObject!`, but cannot find any information about it in the docs.

The signature of `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` in Swift is:

```
func enumerateObjectsUsingBlock(_ block: ((AnyObject!,
                                         Int,
                                         UnsafePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void)!)
```

and in Objective C:

```
- (void)enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id obj,
                                     NSUInteger idx,
                                     BOOL *stop))block
```

If I want to treat the objects that are iterated over as a specific type, in Objective C I simply adjust the signature on the fly, for example:

```
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *s, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    // ...some function of s as NSString, not just id... 
}];
```

How do I get this behaviour in Swift?

Comment: Have you tried casting?

Comment: It works with casting in function body, but that doesn't look quite as ...natural as the adapted signature in Obj-C.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Swift you cannot "tweak" the block/closure signature as in
Objective-C, you have to cast explicitly. Either with an
optional cast:

```
array.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock({ object, index, stop in
    if let str = object as? String {
        println(str)
    }
})
```

or with a forced cast if you are sure that all objects are strings:

```
array.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock({ object, index, stop in
    let str = object as String // `as!` in Swift 1.2
    println(str)
})
```

Since `NSArray` bridges to `Array` seamlessly, you can alternatively
use the `Array` enumeration:

```
for str in array as [String] {
    println(str)
}
```

or, if you need the elements together with their index:

```
for (index, str) in enumerate(array as [String]) {
    println("\(index): \(str)")
}
```

---

Update for **Swift 3.0**

With `enumerateObjects(using:)`:

```
array.enumerateObjects(using: { (object, index, stop) in
    if let str = object as? String {
        print("\(index): \(str)")
    }
})
```

Enumerate as Swift array:

```
if let a = array as? [String] {
    for str in a {
        print(str)
    }
}
```

Enumerate elements and indices as Swift array:

```
if let a = array as? [String] {
    for (index, str) in a.enumerated() {
        print("\(index): \(str)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the swift for/each statement, which automatically provides each element as a variable of the type contained in a swift array:

```
let array: [String] = ["1", "2", "3"]

for element in array {
    println(element) // element is of String type
}
```

With `NSArray` you can use the same statement, but with explicit cast:

```
let nsarray: NSArray = ["1", "2", "3"]

for element in nsarray {
    let value = element as String // note: use `as!` in swift 1.2
    println(value)
}
```

If you still use `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock`:

```
nsarray.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock { (element, index, stop) in
    let stringElement = element as String
    println(stringElement)
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to use `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` to get the objects together with their indexes in one go. I'd definitely use the more simple `for` construct if I don't care for indexes or additional options such as concurrency.